# Kubernetes Unable to mount volumes for pod with timeout

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am trying to mount an NFS volume to my pods but with no success.

I have a server running the nfs mount point, when I try to connect to it from some other running server

`sudo mount -t nfs -o proto=tcp,port=2049 10.0.0.4:/export /mnt` works fine

Another thing worth mentioning is when I remove the volume from the deployment and the pod is running. I log into it and i can telnet to 10.0.0.4 with ports 111 and 2049 successfully. so there really doesnt seem to be any communication problems

as well as:

> ```
> showmount -e 10.0.0.4
> Export list for 10.0.0.4:
> /export/drive 10.0.0.0/16
> /export       10.0.0.0/16
> ```

So I can assume that there is no network or configuration problems between the server and the client (I am using Amazon and the server that i tested on is in the same security group as the k8s minions)

P.S: 
The server is a simple ubuntu->50gb disk

Kubernetes v1.3.4

So I start creating my PV

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: PersistentVolume
> metadata:
>   name: nfs
> spec:
>   capacity:
>     storage: 50Gi
>   accessModes:
>     - ReadWriteMany
>   nfs:
>     server: 10.0.0.4
>     path: "/export"
> ```

And my PVC

> ```
> kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
> apiVersion: v1
> metadata:
>   name: nfs-claim
> spec:
>   accessModes:
>     - ReadWriteMany
>   resources:
>     requests:
>       storage: 50Gi
> ```

here is how kubectl describes them:

> ```
>   Name:       nfs
>     Labels:     <none>
>     Status:     Bound
>     Claim:      default/nfs-claim
>     Reclaim Policy: Retain
>     Access Modes:   RWX
>     Capacity:   50Gi
>     Message:
>     Source:
>         Type:   NFS (an NFS mount that lasts the lifetime of a pod)
>         Server: 10.0.0.4
>         Path:   /export
>         ReadOnly:   false
>     No events.
> ```

AND

> ```
>   Name:       nfs-claim
>     Namespace:  default
>     Status:     Bound
>     Volume:     nfs
>     Labels:     <none>
>     Capacity:   0
>     Access Modes:
>     No events.
> ```

pod deployment:

> ```
>   apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
>     kind: Deployment
>     metadata:
>       name: mypod
>       labels:
>         name: mypod
>     spec:
>       replicas: 1
>       strategy:
>         rollingUpdate:
>           maxSurge: 1
>           maxUnavailable: 0
>         type: RollingUpdate
>       template:
>         metadata:
>           name: mypod
>           labels:
>             # Important: these labels need to match the selector above, the api server enforces this constraint
>             name: mypod
>         spec:
>           containers:
>           - name: abcd
>             image: irrelevant to the question
>             ports:
>             - containerPort: 80
>             env:
>             - name: hello
>               value: world
>             volumeMounts:
>             - mountPath: "/mnt"
>               name: nfs
>           volumes:
>             - name: nfs
>               persistentVolumeClaim:
>                 claimName: nfs-claim
> ```

When I deploy my POD i get the following:

> ```
> Volumes:
>       nfs:
>         Type:   PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
>         ClaimName:  nfs-claim
>         ReadOnly:   false
>       default-token-6pd57:
>         Type:   Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
>         SecretName: default-token-6pd57
>     QoS Tier:   BestEffort
>     Events:
>       FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From                            SubobjectPath   Type        Reason      Message
>       --------- --------    -----   ----                            -------------   --------    ------      -------
>       13m       13m     1   {default-scheduler }                            Normal      Scheduled   Successfully assigned xxx-2140451452-hjeki to ip-10-0-0-157.us-west-2.compute.internal
>       11m       7s      6   {kubelet ip-10-0-0-157.us-west-2.compute.internal}          Warning     FailedMount Unable to mount volumes for pod "xxx-2140451452-hjeki_default(93ca148d-6475-11e6-9c49-065c8a90faf1)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "xxx-2140451452-hjeki"/"default". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[nfs]
>       11m       7s      6   {kubelet ip-10-0-0-157.us-west-2.compute.internal}          Warning     FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "xxx-2140451452-hjeki"/"default". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[nfs]
> ```

Tried everything I know, and everything i can think of. What am i missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I tested version 1.3.4 and 1.3.5 of Kubernetes and NFS mount didn't work for me. Later I switched to the 1.2.5 and that version gave me some more detailed info ( kubectl describe pod ...). It turned out that 'nfs-common' is missing in the hyperkube image. After I added nfs-common to all container instances based on hyperkube image on master and worker nodes the NFS share started to work normally (mount was successful). So that's the case here. I tested it in practice and it solved my problem.

Comment: I can see that the issue is opened so there is a hope for an official fix for this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30310

Comment: Actually the fix is applied in the 'master' branch of the hyperkube image (see Dockerfile definition)